# PHP: How to display date time in following format (2015-01-05T06:27:50.000Z )?

Tags: php, datetime

I want to show the datetime in the following format

```
2015-01-05T06:27:50.000Z
```

How I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.000\Z", strtotime("2015-01-05 06:27:50")); ?>
```

Comment: @Priyank Thanks, It helps and solve the issue, of-course you deserve the up-vote and verified answer :)

Comment: This solution will only work correctly if you are in UTC timezone (or +0000 offset). Use `gmdate()` instead, or use format `c` in `date('c',  ...);`.

Comment: @Glavić Thanks, its very helpful and short cut, If you add your answer into separate response, then I will add an up-vote for you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to include the right timezone offet:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\.Z\Z');
```